# Is there a way I can simplify checking a value is a multiple of something and not 0?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
if (Settings.Trk3 % 20 == 0 && Settings.Trk3 > 0)
    // Do something
```

It looks like there might be a better way to code this but I cannot think how to do it. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: `If (Math.DivRem(Settings.Trk3, 20, out var remainder) > 0 && remainder == 0)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use an extension method if it's a common operation in your codebase - but if it's a one-off check then I'd leave your code as-is because your existing code clearly signals intent and because greater-than-zero and modulo division are distinct operations that should be kept separate.

That said - here's what the extension method looks like:

```
public static class IntegerExtensions
{
    public static Boolean IsNonZeroMultipleOf( this Int32 value, Int32 divisor)
    {
        return ( value > 0 ) && ( value % divisor ) == 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if( Settings.Trk3.IsNonZeroMultipleOf( 20 ) )
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Regarding performance: the JIT should be smart-enough to inline trivial *non-virtual* method-calls, especially to *pure functions*, including extension methods, so it's safe to use this code in a tight-loop if absolutely necessary. (I don't think using the `[Pure]` attribute is necessary).

However, if you want to be an absolutely horrible programmer then use a custom struct with implicit conversion to/from `Int32` and an overloaded operator. This code (abuses) the `>>` operator to perform the same `IsNonZeroMultipleOf` operation described above. (At least by using `>>` it's more obvious to users that something odd is going on instead of overloading the `%` operator):

```
public struct MyInteger
{
    private readonly Int32 value;

    public MyInteger( Int32 value )
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator Int32( MyInteger mi ) => mi.value;
    public static implicit operator MyInteger( Int32 value ) => new MyInteger( value );

    public static Boolean operator >>(MyInteger value, Int32 divisor)
    {
        return ( value.value > 0 ) && ( value.value % divisor ) == 0;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Note that `Settings.Trk3` is still an `Int32`. The assignment to `MyInteger` works because of the `implicit operator` feature.

MyInteger mi = Settings.Trk3;
if( mi >> 20 )
{
    // Do something.
}
```

Because this code is using value-type'd structs, makes only non-virtual calls and has no heap allocations (`new` is used for stack-allocation of structs in C#, not just for the GC heap) this code should also be good to use in performance-critical code with zero impact.